# NSBundle, can it be used to save a project document?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsbundle

I'm building a Mac OS X application that can be used to create 'projects'. When a user saves a project, they will be saving many resources: image files, text files, sqlite files etc.

I can either create a folder in Documents for each project, and within that folder I can place all the project assets, and just include a single project file that is used to open the project.

I've read about NSBundle which I'd like to use. But I've only read about them in the context of application bundles. Is it possible to use NSBundle in this way? Where the user only sees a single file, and can move it wherever they like.

Does it make sense to do what I'm trying, using NSBundle? Or is there another way to do this?

(I'm fairly new to MacOS X programming)

**UPDATE**

I believe iPhoto uses this method to store the "iPhoto Library", this is what I'd like to do with my application, is NSBundle what I should be looking into?

Comment: A lot of Apple's own apps use document bundles. Older versions of iWork created uncompressed bundles, iWork '09 zips the final bundle. (you can test that by renaming any Pages document to *.zip. The Archive Utility will decompress it into a document bundle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and was used in quite a few apps in the past. The method is described in [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/DocumentPackages/DocumentPackages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH106-SW1). Once it's clearly declared in your app's `Info.plist`, Finder will show the resulting bundle as one file.

However, I can't recommend you to do that. Apple's own Keynote was using the bundle approach in the past, but it no longer uses it any more. Similarly, OmniGraffle (which is a diagramming app on OS X with a long history) used bundles to save projects, but it stopped doing that, too.

The reason is that the bundle is still seen as a directory by the non-Apple email software, or any browser, etc, although the Finder shows it as a file. It would be a mess if a user wants to attach your document in the bundle format to an email s/he is composing in Gmail inside a browser, say. That confused a lot of people.

So, it's possible, but I don't recommend it. One way out is to use the zipped bundle as the user-visible file, and to unzip it when the user opens it into a temporary directory. Then you can use `NSBundle` and/or `NSFileWrapper` apis to access files inside it.

Comment: Thanks Yuji, interesting to hear the background to this approach. I do find the zip method you mention quite attractive. It's true that users of my application may well be interested in sharing their work with each other, and in future this may take place between a Mac and a Windows user.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's File Wrapper sample seems to be what you want:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/PersistentDocumentFileWrappers/Introduction/Intro.html

It also demonstrates how to save a Core Data persistent store in the bundle. You can leave that part out if you just want to store resources.

Answer (score 0):

The *NSBundle* class represents the application bundle, and can be used to access resources within the applicationm but you would you it for application data, not user data.

For each of the resources you mention, there's a way of saving this type, for example, for image files, you could use *NSData* to save the image data to disk, and for text files you could use the method `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:`.

You may very well want to take a look at *Core Data* (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html), a very good framework for managing the user's data model, to see if this would fit your needs.

Comment: Not just the application bundle; frameworks and most plug-ins are also bundles.

Comment: Sure, good point. Although in Rew's case, this is an application bundle.

Comment: I'm talking about using bundles to store documents created by my application, as in the iPhoto example.

Comment: Rew, that’s not a _bundle_, it’s a _package_. As weicshel alludes to, you want `NSFileWrapper`.